# mongodb - look up table like SQL?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, nosql

Suppose I have a data structure in the form of `[String, int]`, I would like to be able to do lookups in `O(1)` time. In traditional SQL databases, I can simply create a look-up table.

How can I translate the same to mongodb such that I can use the `String` element as the `key` and `int` as the `value`?

Comment: why don't you just create a new collection just like a table in SQL for look ups ?

Comment: Only hash-based indexes would be O(1), which is not universally available, and not often the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MongoDB, your documents would need to be structured like this:

```
{
   key: "the key name"
   value: 100
}
```

Then, you'd create an index:

```
db.myLookupTable.ensureIndex({key : 1})
```

It's not going to be `O(1)` time though as it's not a Hash lookup. As explained [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/#behavior-of-index-types), indexes, by default, in MongoDB are B-tree based so that other types of operations are possible (like sorting which you could not get from a Hash-based index). B-trees are worst case `O(log n)`.

You could also enable the Hashed indexes for an index in MongoDB:

```
db.myLookupTable.ensureIndex({key: "hashed" })
```

That limits the types of queries you can do on the index though. For example, range queries are not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on hashed indexes!

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB allows you to create an index on fields in a collection; however, these are B-tree indexes and would result in lookups that are O(log n).

If you need O(1) lookups, then I would suggest using Redis.

Comment: WiredPrairie makes a valid suggestion in that the index can be "hashed"; if you are using MongoDB 2.4